# Google OAuth Consent Screen for Firebase applications

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-signin, google-apps, google-console-developer

Im trying to build a React-Native mobile application and the backend is totally depending on Firebase (im using Firestore as a database) I dont have any website or host service connected to this app except Firebase.

Now, on https://console.developers.google.com/ if i want to publish my app(keys) for i.e.: google sign in, im asked about a privacy policy and Terms&Conditions that should be hosted on the domains: [image: Screenshot of my app]

I have filled those fields like that but it doesnt seem right and in the future could be a problem. Can someone share their experience with Google APIs for applications that need sigin? What are the best practices?